# WordPress logs out after using /wp-admin/admin.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm currently updating a system with a new function. I'm adding the `show_user_profile` and `edit_user_profile` action to add custom data into the user-view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bindRemoveButton() {
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('table.available-users button.remove').on('click', function() {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });
        });
    }

    bindRemoveButton();
</script>
<table class="form-table available-users">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="accounts"><?php print __('Assigned accounts', ZVA_I18N); ?></label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/templates/admin/user_add_box.php#TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550" title="<?php print __('Add User', ZVA_I18N); ?>" class="thickbox button button-primary"><?php print __('Add', ZVA_I18N); ?></button>
            </th>
            <td>
                <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed users">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="manage-colum" style="padding-left: 20px;"><span><?php print __('Username', ZVA_I18N); ?></span></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="manage-colum"><span><?php print __('Date From', ZVA_I18N); ?></span></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="manage-colum"><span><?php print __('Date To', ZVA_I18N); ?></span></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="manage-colum"><span><?php print __('Action', ZVA_I18N); ?></span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            foreach($user_available AS $aindex => $available_user) {
                                $user = new WP_User($available_user['user_id']);
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php print $user->user_login; ?> (<?php print $user->display_name; ?>)</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="jumper_day_from[<?php print $user->ID; ?>]" size="2" value="<?php print date('d', $available_user['from']); ?>" placeholder="DD" />.
                                            <input type="text" name="jumper_month_from[<?php print $user->ID; ?>]" size="2" value="<?php print date('m', $available_user['from']); ?>" placeholder="MM" />.
                                            <input type="text" name="jumper_year_from[<?php print $user->ID; ?>]" size="4" value="<?php print date('Y', $available_user['from']); ?>" placeholder="YYYY" /> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="jumper_day_to[<?php print $user->ID; ?>]" size="2" value="<?php print date('d', $available_user['to']); ?>" placeholder="DD" />.
                                            <input type="text" name="jumper_month_to[<?php print $user->ID; ?>]" size="2" value="<?php print date('m', $available_user['to']); ?>" placeholder="MM" />.
                                            <input type="text" name="jumper_year_to[<?php print $user->ID; ?>]" size="4" value="<?php print date('Y', $available_user['to']); ?>" placeholder="YYYY" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="remove button button-primary"><?php print __('Remove', ZVA_I18N); ?></button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Okay, no problems. See the **Line 19** on my code, here i add a Link/Button to open a new Thickbox with additional content. When i click on the link, a thickbox pops up and displays the content from the File `/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/templates/admin/user_add_box.php`.

To use WordPress's own functions (like `$wpdb` or other), im including the `admin.php` on the `user_add_box.php` - YES, currently that's only these line on the file:

```
<?php
    define('WP_ADMIN', true);

    /* Nativate to /wp-admin/ directory */
    require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))))) . '/wp-admin/admin.php');
?>
```

When i'm open the tickbox, the login will be shown - curiously. After that i'm complete logged out from WordPress.

I work very very long with WordPress and never had such problems. Especially since I also developing for years themes and plugins for WordPress.

Can you tell me, what i'm doing wrong? Why the system logs me out?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

After see the core file, i see i must define constants like `define('WP_ADMIN', true);`, but  thats dont solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the `auth_redirect` method (`wp-includes/pluggable.php`) will be checked if the file comes from `wp-admin` directory:

```
 if ( $secure && !is_ssl() && false !== strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') )
```

If not, the system will be redirect automatical to the `wp-login.php`.

Solve it to rewrite the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable:

```
<?php
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'wp-admin';
    require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))))) . '/wp-admin/admin.php');
?>
```

Otherwise, add only `wp-load.php` and `wp-admin/includes/admin.php`:

```
<?php
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))))) . '/wp-load.php');
    require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))))) . '/wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
?>
```